FirestonePigeonParser.h Issues while Compiling on Xcode
I'm trying to compile on flutter code on XCode and I keep getting this new issue.
It says "Expected a type" and "Unknown receiver 'FIRFilter'; did you. mean'CIFilter'?' `17x in this section of code.
Has anyone run into this before while trying to compile flutter code on Xcode?
These are my versions:
I have this at the top of my Podfile. I'm running Xcode 15.4.
$FirebaseSDKVersion = '9.6.0'
platform :ios, '14.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  mobile_scanner: ^2.1.0
  qr_scanner_overlay: ^0.0.2
  qr_flutter: ^4.1.0
  firebase_core: ^2.16.0
#  firebase_auth: ^5.1.1
  firebase_storage: ^11.2.7
  cloud_firestore: ^4.9.2
  image_picker: ^1.1.2

+ (FIRFilter *_Nonnull)filterFromJson:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *_Nullable)map {
  if (map[@"fieldPath"]) {
    // Deserialize a FilterQuery
    NSString *op = map[@"op"];
    FIRFieldPath *fieldPath = map[@"fieldPath"];
    id value = map[@"value"];

    // All the operators from Firebase
    if ([op isEqualToString:@"=="]) {
      return [FIRFilter filterWhereFieldPath:fieldPath isEqualTo:value];
    } else if ([op isEqualToString:@"!="]) {
      return [FIRFilter filterWhereFieldPath:fieldPath isNotEqualTo:value];
    } else if ([op isEqualToString:@"<"]) {
      return [FIRFilter filterWhereFieldPath:fieldPath isLessThan:value];
    } else if ([op isEqualToString:@"<="]) {
      return [FIRFilter filterWhereFieldPath:fieldPath isLessThanOrEqualTo:value];
    } else if ([op isEqualToString:@">"]) {
      return [FIRFilter filterWhereFieldPath:fieldPath isGreaterThan:value];
    } else if ([op isEqualToString:@">="]) {
      return [FIRFilter filterWhereFieldPath:fieldPath isGreaterThanOrEqualTo:value];
    } else if ([op isEqualToString:@"array-contains"]) {
      return [FIRFilter filterWhereFieldPath:fieldPath arrayContains:value];
    } else if ([op isEqualToString:@"array-contains-any"]) {
      return [FIRFilter filterWhereFieldPath:fieldPath arrayContainsAny:value];
    } else if ([op isEqualToString:@"in"]) {
      return [FIRFilter filterWhereFieldPath:fieldPath in:value];
    } else if ([op isEqualToString:@"not-in"]) {
      return [FIRFilter filterWhereFieldPath:fieldPath notIn:value];
    } else {
      @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"InvalidOperator"
                                     reason:@"Invalid operator"
                                   userInfo:nil];
    }
  }

Trying lower and lower firestore versions with no luck.
Image from XCode
